# Why becomeFirstResponder causes crash in iOS?

Tags: ios

I want to use `UIMenuController` with my `UITableViewCell`,

so I add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` in the customized label in my cell like

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
-(void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longRecognizer
{
    if (longRecognizer.state!=UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        return;
    }

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    UIMenuItem *copy = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"copy" action:@selector(copyText:)];
    UIMenuItem *report = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"report" action:@selector(reportText:)];

    UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
    [menu setMenuItems:@[copy, report]];
    [menu setTargetRect:longRecognizer.view.bounds inView:longRecognizer.view];
    [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];

    NSLog(@"menu show");
}
```

but I got a crash at `[self becomeFirstResponder]`

and console log shows

`_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)`

`_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)`

what happended?

Comment: you are assigning deallocated object in becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: @CodeHunterr do you mean the customized label is deallocated?But the label is not deallocated when I debug the code

Comment: just add [yourlable/textfield becomeFirstResponder].

Comment: @CodeHunterr `self` is my label